# ASP.NET Core page Razor enum dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I use Asp.Core 2.1 with "Page Razor Crud" and I want into my page show a dropdownlist.

Here's my model:

```
public enum EnumStatus
    {
        Waiting,
        [Display(Name = "Development progress")]
        Progress,
        Canceled,
        Refused,
        Deployed,
    }
    public class Improvement
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public EnumStatus Status { get; set; }
    }
```

the CRUD Razor Page generated this line:

```
<select asp-for="Improvement.Status" class="form-control"></select>
```

But it's empty. After researchs, i found I need to add asp-items. But at this point, all solutions I tested failed.

Best regards,

Answer (score 13):

Try the following code in the view:

```
<select asp-for="Status" 
        asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<EnumStatus>()" 
        class="form-control>
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

Here `Status` is the property of your `Improvement` model class while `EnumStatus` is the name of your enum type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, "<EnumStatus*> missing assembly?

Comment: add fully qualified name with namespace or add using statement